# How can i display Images / Star in a Material Angular Form

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a form that displays the rating in form of star images, my back end stores it as a number in string format. So while i am playing arround i am wondering what the best material input would be to achieve this. I got this so far

[image]

I am using input with the below code

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput placeholder="Service Value"
    formControlName ="serviceValue">
    <span>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let[].constructor(NumberConverter(form.controls.serviceValue.value))">
       <img class="star" src="../../assets/images/basic-5-point-gold-star-beveled.jpg" />
    </ng-container>
   </span>
</mat-form-field>
```

If there is no better mat controle to do this how do i get rid of the value 5 and be able to move my stars up. Also i hope it helps me to get rid of this error i am getting which points to this section.

> SurveyResponseComponent.html:113 ERROR RangeError: Invalid array
>   length
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SurveyResponseComponent.html:119)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44270)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44564)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:44636)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the image but with the ngFor statement

```
let[].constructor(NumberConverter(form.controls.serviceValue.value))
```

The template compiler is not going to be able to parse that.

Create a pipe that returns an array from a number.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'arrayFromNumber'
})
export class ArrayFromNumberPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(length) {
    return Array.from({ length: length }, (_, i) => i);
  }
}
```

And use it

```
*ngFor="let i of form.controls.serviceValue.value| arrayFromNumber"
```

See this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzvkyb

Comment: i actually was able to fix the error by moving the NumberConverter from the template to the controller when the value is assigned. But this still doesnt solve my main problem on how to not display the 5 and place the images where the input box is

Comment: Having templates that call methods on the component should be avoided, it is a huge performance hit as the methods need to be called each time change detection is triggered. That is why pipes exist, they are only called if the input to the pipe has changed. Otherwise you are continually recreating an array and rebinding to that array on every change detection cycle rather than just when the input updates.

Comment: thanks, the solution to my problem was simpler then i thought, i just made the <input matInput hidden> and that did the trick

Comment: Here is an article on using ControlValueAccessor to create a star input if you want the user to be able to click on the stars https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

Comment: Thanks, in my case i only need to display the values as the user input was done with jquery and ajax to be smaller and faster to load for users